# get the list of active windows in wayland weston

Tags: window, wayland, qtwayland

How to get the list of active windows in wayland.. 
ie, in my window one terminal is active and a calculator is also active, I need to get the details of these windows in terminal , how can I get it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to use wayland with embedded systems, so  using

> Genivi ivi-layermanager

I am able to see the layers created and all details about the layers, Thanks for your support.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Is `Genivi` a command-line tool that should be installed? What package is it in in e.g. ubuntu?

Comment: Genivi is open source automobile software, including [IVI Layer Manager](https://at.projects.genivi.org/wiki/display/PROJ/ILM+-+IVI+Layer+Manager) and [wayland-ivi-extension](https://github.com/GENIVI/wayland-ivi-extension). It seems unlikely you'll want to use their library, but perhaps Genivi had the same issue and found a workaround you can duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you can't. The main idea of the Wayland protocol is that a client doesn't know anything about the rest of the world.

You can, however, modify your compositor so that it will record the information you need about every windows in it and use those informations at will. Modifying a compositor, however, is a bit complex for a SO answer (and beyond my knowledge) so I guess you'll have to look around for good tutorials.