# How to get the pid of the focused window on GNOME (Wayland)

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

```
xdotool getactivewindow getwindowpid
```

I tried this. But it's not working on Wayland. As far as i know. There is no focus window concept on Wayland. So can I get it from Mutter or GNOME-Shell?

Comment: I wish that ability too. My current best is using Looking Glass. "[Alt+F2] lg [Enter]" to open it. It does not tell pid but it shows app name, which I can then search in System Monitor and not have to look through tens of processes. There you can get PID or kill the app directly. I hope this helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the active window on Gnome Wayland?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45465016/how-do-i-get-the-active-window-on-gnome-wayland)