# On Wayland is there a way today to get the currently focused windows title and process ID?

Tags: process, window, x11, wayland

On X11 I used to use `xprop` to get information about active windows but on Wayland that tool doesn't work anymore.
There have been questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45465016/how-do-i-get-the-active-window-on-gnome-wayland), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802683/get-the-list-of-active-windows-in-wayland-weston) one which ask basically the same question as I do, and the answer is: no, this is not intended and won't be supported by Wayland.

This is why I won't switch to Wayland until I'm forced to, but maybe Wayland has changed since 2017?

So I rephrase the question: as today, is there a way to programmatically get the currently active window *title* and *PID* on Wayland?

Maybe even a convienient Python library?

Comment: Was looking for the same none of my "fetch if open, else create" window tools work anymore.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362731/how-to-identify-window-by-clicking-in-wayland) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

My method of doing this (which is scuffed but works) is to use `Rofi` in Window mode.

```bash
rofi -show window
```

It'll bring up a little list of the currently open windows, as well as their titles and descriptions. Knowing window titles, I bet you could find PIDs.